# Find out where [ shortcode ] leads in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, square-bracket

I'm no word press guru, but I think i have a good grip how to manage a site. The problem I'm having is that I have a site which i haven't done myself and i'm trying to delete a product from a page.

The page only have `[productspage]` as content though and i cannot for the life of me figure out where it gets the data from. Is there any way to find out where `[productspage]` gets the data? I've checked in widgets and other pages but even though i search i cannot find anything.

Comment: Is there any plugin installed for product management? I think site using `WP E-Commerce plugin`.

Comment: Not that i can find. The products is added in wp's standard product handler

Comment: Can you share website URL?

Comment: http://www.dofab.se/produktsida/produkter/dorrar/   Heres the url to the productpage that i want to remove a product from

Comment: As I said , your site is using Wp-Ecommere plugin. Go to your plugin list and you will find that.

Comment: Totally missed that one, thank you for your help

Comment: No problem , hope you will manage now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access on the FTP, download the files in a local machine. Then use a software like [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and its feature of "Search in files".

Choose all the folders you downloaded from the FTP and search for the name of the Shortcode. In your example, search for `productspage` without the brackets of the shortcode.

Probably, you will have many results. Some put it in `functions.php`, some others in new files. You need to find the right one which is a function with a similar name of productspage. Just to be sure, close to that function, you will find also something like this:

`add_shortcode('productspage','the_name_of_the_function_you_found');`

That function is what you are looking for. You will be able to check how it works and from where it retrieve the data.

Comment: You can also do this in your functions.php file(for instance): `var_dump( $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']['productspage'] );`. This will give you just the name of the function that renders this shortcode(or an array of class name/object and method), so you would still have to find it in the source code. If you get the name of a regular function, you can add this: `var_dump( new ReflectionFunction('name_of_the_function'))->getFileName() );` in order to get the file where the function is defined.